# why heroku memory increase in flask? error code : H14

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I don`t speak english well. but I want to solve this error.
why heroku memory continually increase?(when i use my web app)

heroku error code is H14 like this :

```
 Process running mem=541M(105.8%)
 Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
 ========== after app running ===============
 Process running mem=831M(162.4%)
 Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
 ========== after app running ===============
 Process running mem=856M(167.3%)
 Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

I want to memory restore(?) (like 541M > 831M > 541M) but, memory always increase ,not decrease ,so I finally run heroku restart.

I don't want to restart, I want to decrease memory. What should I do?
sorry, i`m very not good at english. thanks.

this is my python code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import cv2
import numpy
import gc
import face_detection
import predict

from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
from keras.models import load_model

app = Flask(__name__,  static_url_path="/static")



print("시작 ")
detector = MTCNN()
model = load_model('./static/keras_model/1layer_128_1_best(1)-SGD.h5')
print("로딩됨")
@app.route('/')

def render_file():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/file_uploaded',methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':  # POST 방식으로 전달된 경우
        f = request.files['upload_image'].read()
        # # 파일 객체 혹은 파일 스트림을 가져오고, html 파일에서 넘겨지는 값의 이름을 file1으로 했기 때문에 file1임.
        # 업로드된 파일을 특정 폴더에저장하고,

        # convert string data to numpy array
        npimg = numpy.fromstring(f, dtype=numpy.uint8)
        # convert numpy array to image
        img = cv2.imdecode(npimg, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        if img.shape[0] > 500 or img.shape[1] > 500:
            if img.shape[0] > img.shape[1]:
                bigger = img.shape[0]
            else :
                bigger = img.shape[1]
            scale_percent =  (bigger - 500)  *100 / bigger
            width = int(img.shape[1] * (100-scale_percent) / 100)
            height = int(img.shape[0] * (100- scale_percent) / 100)
            dim = (width, height)
            img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        print(img.shape)


        # 이거때문에 face_extract 때문에 올라감
        face_extract = face_detection.input_image(detector, img)
        print("얼굴추출 완료")
        if len(face_extract) == 0:
            print("얼굴인식 못했음")
            return render_template('fail_back.html')
        else:
            result, k = predict.prediction(face_extract, model)

            iu_percent = round(float(k[0][0] * 100), 3)
            suzy_percent = round(float(k[0][1]) * 100, 3)

            # return send_file(file_object, mimetype='image/jpeg')
            if iu_percent > suzy_percent:
                return render_template('result.html', image_file="image/result_iu.jpg", not_similler="수지",
                                       not_similler_percent=suzy_percent, similler="아이유", similler_percent=iu_percent)
            else:
                return render_template('result.html', image_file="image/result_suzy.jpg", not_similler="아이유",
                                       not_similler_percent=iu_percent, similler="수지", similler_percent=suzy_percent)
    else:
        return render_template('fail_back.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # debug를 True로 세팅하면, 해당 서버 세팅 후에 코드가 바뀌어도 문제없이 실행됨.
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

I post my code. my code pick one person. It tells which one of the two looks more like.

my app site : simstest.herokuapp.com

but, When you use a site, the Heroku memory increases and the site restarts.

- oh, I find memory increaseing method.

  ```
  import gc
  def face_eye_trace(data,result_list):

    for result in result_list :


        x = int(result['box'][0])
        y = int(result['box'][1])
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        if y < 0:
            y = 0
        width = int(result['box'][2])
        height = int(result['box'][3])

        img3 = data[y:y + height, x:x + width]

        return img3

  def input_image(input_detector,pixels_image):

    detector = input_detector
    pixels = pixels_image

    try:

        # 이것때문에 memory 증가===============
        faces = detector.detect_faces(pixels)

        print(len(faces))

        if len(faces) == 0:
            return []
        elif len(faces) == 1 :
            face_detection = face_eye_trace(pixels,faces)
        else :
            print("다수의 얼굴이 인식되어 종료했습니다.")
            return []
    except:
        print("얼굴 인식을 하지 못하였습니다.")
        return []


    print("detection:" ,gc.collect())

    return face_detection
  ```

this code method  ' face_detection = face_eye_trace(pixels,faces) ' caused memory increase.

why this method increase memory?  and Why don't this automatically return the memory after this method?

Comment: Did you find any solution bro?

Answer (score 1):

[Garbage Collector interface module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) (`gc`) is exactly what you could use here to further debug this problem.

To debug a leaking program call:

```
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)
```

This will output debugging information about garbage collection into your console.

For further debugging, `gc` module provides more facilities, including ability to list out all objects tracked by the garbage collector, disable/enable collector or manually trigger garbage collection.

If you don't have a leak and want to just lower memory usage, try using `gc.set_threshold` to trigger garbage collection at a lower memory usage point.